# How to configure IntelliJ terminal for Powerlevel9k?

Tags: intellij-idea, zsh, iterm2

I'm using macOS and Zsh shell with iTerm2. I started customizing the shell with Powerlevel9k and then I realized that my terminal in IntelliJ looks really off, and I can't  figure out how to fix it.

I tried to change color settings, but it did not take any affect.

[image: iterm2]
[image: intellij]

Comment: FYI: There is powerlevel10k now.

Comment: Yeah, this was my first time configuring my terminal, so I was just following along some tutorials, until i noticed that powerlevel10k was released, thank you for the feed back :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Settings(Preferences) | Editor | Color Scheme | Console Colors options.